# HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse not working with Load Balance Strategy in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

Environment:

- Ubuntu: 20.04 Server LTS
- Apache NIFI: 1.20.0
- docker 23.0

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.16.0"

services:
  zookeeper:
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  nifi-1:
    image: apache/nifi:1.20.0
    container_name: nifi-1
    hostname: nifi-1
    ports:
      - 10180:8880
      - 19180:9180
    environment:
      NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_SECURE: false
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST: nifi-1
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: 9180
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY: 4a5cZnr7WpfZlMrr/Ub2Bo7jdx+mDkPa
      NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE: true
      NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT: 8082
      NIFI_CLUSTER_ADDRESS: nifi-1
      NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING: "zookeeper:2181"
      NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT: "1 min"
    volumes:
      - /opt/nifi/nifi-3rd-extensions:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions

  nifi-2:
    image: apache/nifi:1.20.0
    container_name: nifi-2
    hostname: nifi-2
    ports:
      - 10280:8880
      - 19280:9180
    environment:
      NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_SECURE: false
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST: nifi-2
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: 9180
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY: 4a5cZnr7WpfZlMrr/Ub2Bo7jdx+mDkPa
      NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE: true
      NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT: 8082
      NIFI_CLUSTER_ADDRESS: nifi-2
      NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING: "zookeeper:2181"
      NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT: "1 min"
    volumes:
      - /opt/nifi/nifi-3rd-extensions:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions

  nifi-3:
    image: apache/nifi:1.20.0
    container_name: nifi-3
    hostname: nifi-3
    ports:
      - 10380:8880
      - 19380:9180
    environment:
      NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_SECURE: false
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT:
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST: nifi-3
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: 9180
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_KEYSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE:
      NIFI_SECURITY_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE:
      NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY: 4a5cZnr7WpfZlMrr/Ub2Bo7jdx+mDkPa
      NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE: true
      NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT: 8082
      NIFI_CLUSTER_ADDRESS: nifi-3
      NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING: "zookeeper:2181"
      NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT: "1 min"
    volumes:
      - /opt/nifi/nifi-3rd-extensions:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions
```

Below is my nifi flow:

The main flow is:

```
HandleHttpRequest --> P6XmlParser --> P6SimpleAcknowedge --> HandleHttpResponse
```

[image]

The property of HandleHttpRequest is:
[image]
[image]

If I don't config any Load Balance Strategy in Queues, the nifi flow can work good.

If I config a Load Balance Strategy in any Qeueu on the main path, then some time the client can not get the response. For example, if I config Load Balance Strategy as "Round robin" in the Queue between P6XmlParser and P6SimpleAcknowledge, the client can not get the response sometime. I guess the reason is that after Load Balance in the Queue, the flow redirect the flowfile to other HandleHtpResponse which is the on the same node of the income HandleHttpResponse.

If my guess is correct, how do I fix this problem so that this flow can distribute the income flowfile to other nodes and eventually return to the HandleHttpResponse of the original node ? Or any other suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Do you use LoadBalancer component?

Comment: @AmitVujic not yet. Although I plan to use nginx as the reverse proxy with the function of load balance, at this moment, I think I need to firgure it out whether NIFI can approach this isseu in it's core function. If this issue can not be solved with NIFI core functions, nex step I will try a reverse proxy with load balance.

Comment: your flow is really wired. handlehttpresponse should be connected with handlehttprequest.

Comment: @daggett As you said, if handlehttpresponse should be connected with handlehttprequest, I will use ListenHttp enough. Besides, by watching https://youtu.be/e3SpLOZUgHI?t=340 , some custom flow following by handlehttprequest should be an acceptable approach.

Comment: There are could be other processors in-between, but there should be a flow that allows flowfile from request to go to response. That what I mean by linked.

Comment: Also flowfile should stay on the same node between request/response

Comment: @daggett HandleHttpRequest --> P6XmlParser --> P6SimpleAcknowledge --> HandleHttpResponse.

Comment: @daggett "flowfile should stay on the same node between request/response". By adopting Load Balance Strategy in queues among HandleHttpRequest --> P6XmlParser --> P6SimpleAcknowledge --> HandleHttpResponse, how to I control each flowfile eventually back to HandleHttpResponse of its original node ?

Comment: i'm quite sure it's not possible to return flowfile to initial node. however, you are going to make load balancing on http level - no need to make secondary load balancing (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Why Docker compose?  How much throughput do you have that you need to load balance?

Put them on a server without docker and add a lot more RAM.

Load balancing off of the server for web connected is not good, have client calling into a balanced group of IPs.

Comment: The real throughput could be up to 600 milllions xml files coming in every day.

the environment in docker is just my proof of concept. when the flow is complete, I will move them into physical servers.
As to the reverse proxy, I know it could become another bottleneck. So I do think of asking clients to directlly connect to each node of the cluster.